# How can this problem be solved in $O(n^{3/2}log(n))$ time?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

I can solve the following [problem by Jeff Erickson](https://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/book/03-dynprog.pdf) in $O(n^3)$(and maybe in $O(n^2logn)$) time but how is the $O(n^{3/2} log(n))$ time solution possible?

> Let $D[1 .. n]$ be an array of digits, each an integer between $0$ and $9$. A **digital subsequence** of $D$ is a sequence of positive integers composed in the usual way from disjoint substrings of $D$. For example, $3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 32, 38, 46, 64, 83, 279$ is a digital subsequence of the first several digits of $\pi$:$$ \underline 3 , 1, \underline 4 , 1, \underline 5 , 9, 2, \underline 6 , 5, 3, 5, \underline 8 , \underline 9 , 7, 9, \underline{3, 2} , 3, 8, \underline{4, 6} , 2, \underline{6, 4} , 3, 3, \underline{8, 3 }, \underline {2, 7, 9}$$ The length of a digital subsequence is the number of integers it contains, not the number of digits; the preceding example has length $12$. As usual, a digital subsequence is **increasing** if each number is larger than its predecessor.
>
> Describe and analyze an efficient algorithm to compute the longest increasing digital subsequence of $D$. [*Hint: Be careful about your computational assumptions. How long does it take to compare two k-digit numbers?*]
>
> For full credit, your algorithm should run in $O(n^4)$ time; faster algorithms are worth extra credit. The fastest algorithm I know for this problem runs in $O(n^{3/2}log n)$ time; achieving this bound requires several tricks, both in the design of the algorithm and in its analysis, but nothing outside the scope of this class.

Comment: This is known as the longest increasing subsequence : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence

Comment: There is an optimal subsequence consisting of one or more 1 digit numbers, one or more 2 digit numbers, and so on, and no number is ten times larger than the previous one. Otherwise just drop the last digits of numbers.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume you know how to solve the problem by keeping a table $T[i, j]$
which stores the length of the best solution whose last integer is $D[i\cdots j] = D[i]D[i+1] \cdots D[j]$. To compute $T[i, j]$ you need to find the best $T[a, b]$ such that $D[a \cdots b] <_{\text{lex}} D[i \cdots j]$ and $b < i$. The computation of $T[i, j]$ (provided the previous entries of $T$ have been filled) can take $O(n)$ if the $<_{\text{lex}}$ is implemented in $O(1)$ time with a good data structure like a suffix array + LCP; after all, you're always comparing substrings of $D$.  Naively, this would yield a runtime of $O(n^3)$ which is the state at which you seem to be.

Now consider the following observations.

**Observation 1**: The $i$-th term of the optimal sequence should never be longer than the $i-1$-th term by more than 1 digit.

**Observation 2**: Taking $D[1]$, $D[2\cdots3]$, $D[4 \cdots 6], \ldots D[n-\sqrt{n} \cdots n]$  is always a solution, implying that the answer is always at least $\sqrt{n}$, and by Observation 1, we get that only the cells of $T$ with $j-i+1 \leq \sqrt{n}$ should be computed (one can even limit it to $j-i+1 \leq \sqrt{j}$, but it doesn't help asymptotically...). There are now $O(n^{3/2})$ cells.

Now let's try to speed-up the computation of
\begin{equation}
T[i, j] = 1 + \max_{a \leq b < i}  \Big\{ T[a, b] \; \vert  \; D[a\cdots b] <_{\text{lex}} D[i\cdots j] \Big\}.\tag{1}
\end{equation}

As you were already doing in your $O(n^3)$ approach, we should only consider $b - a = j - i$ or $b-a = j - i -1$ (this is just Observation 1).
If we keep, for each substring length $\ell \in \{1, \ldots, \sqrt{n}\}$ a matrix where $B[\ell][i] := \max_{b < i} \Big\{ T[b-\ell+1, b]\Big\}$, then $B[j-i-1][i]$ is one candidate for the $\max$ in Equation (1), while the other candidate will be

$$
\max_{b < i}  \Big\{ T[b-j+i+1, b] \; \vert  \; D[a\cdots b] <_{\text{lex}} D[i\cdots j] \Big\}.
$$

How could we compute this last amount more efficiently? We can assume we're constructing $T[i, j]$ in increasing order of $i$, and let the length be denoted $\ell = j-i+1$. We can keep in memory a set of pairs $$S^{i}_\ell = \Big\{ (T[b-\ell+1, b], D[b-\ell+1 \cdots b]) \; \vert \;  b < i\Big\}.$$

If we let $w = D[i\cdots j]$, then we're looking for
$$
\max v \; \text{s.t. } \; (v, y) \in S^i_{\ell} \text{ and } y <_{\text{lex}} w.
$$

We're now facing a data structures problem; how can we keep a set of pairs $(\text{integer}, \text{string of length } \leq \sqrt{n})$ in a way that quickly allows us to query with a word $w$ for the maximum first coordinate whose second coordinate is smaller than $w$? It is enough to maintain $S$ as a balanced binary search tree, where the ordering of the tree is based solely on the words $y$ inserted in it, but every node keeps track of the best value $v$ present in its subtree. Notice that because comparisons between strings take $O(1)$, searching on the tree will take $O(\log n)$. Therefore our entire algorithm runs in $O(n^{3/2} \log n)$.